# How to repair a file on a truecrypt virtual encrypted disk?

Tags: encryption, ntfs, data-recovery, truecrypt

I have a file (say `volume.tc`), which is a virtual encrypted disk.
When I mount with `sudo truecrypt volume.tc /mnt/v`, I can access most of the files, but one file on this volume (say `corruptedfilename.sh`) got corrupt
for some unknown reason: for example, when I call `ls`, it says `ls: cannot open corruptedfilename.sh: Input/output error`.

**I tried:**

1. Using `ntfsfix`. I have only the mount point (`/mnt/v`), but `ntfsfix` asks for a device name (`/dev/...`). `df -T` reports filesystem type `fuseblk` (looks like a nickname for NTFS) and device `/dev/mapper/truecrypt1`. However `ntfsfix /dev/mapper/truecrypt1` doesn't work (it says `Refusing to operate on read-write mounted device /dev/mapper/truecrypt1.`).
2. `rm /mnt/v/path/to/corruptedfilename.sh` gives `rm: cannot remove "/mnt/v/path/to/corruptedfilename.sh": Input/output error`.

**The question:** Is there a way to recover `corruptedfilename.sh`, or at least delete it, so I would be able to create it again?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Comment: Use truecrypt --filesystem=none to make disk device available on /dev/mapper/truecryptX, without real mounting a filesystem